# How to get value from quote_address table in Magento2

Tags: magento2.3, checkout, payment-methods, quote, shopping-cart

How to get value from quote_address table for checkout and cart page in Magento2.
Need values for guest and login user both in Magento2 cart and checkout page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `quote` object.

You can access `quote_address` data like:

```
echo $quote->getBillingAddress()->getId(); // billing address id
echo $quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();
echo $quote->getShippingAddress()->getId(); // shipping address id
echo $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
```

If you have `$quoteId`

```
protected $quoteRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    ....
}

then can get quote by:

$quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($quoteId);
```

Comment: It is working thanks

Comment: welcome @Webdeveloper :)